# React Native onPress active state change image source on Carousel

Tags: react-native

Trying to change image of a button on my carousel elements, currently it (below code) changes all the images when I click any of them. I'd like change that only current carousel's image. Any ideas? Thanks

```
class CarouselImages extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            myImagesArray: [
                {
                    key: 1,
                    title: 'Category'
                },
                {
                    key: 2,
                    title: 'Category'
                },
                {
                    key: 3,
                    title: 'Category'
                }
            ],
            icon_active: false,
        }

        activateCarouselButton = a => {
            const newState = Object.assign(
                {},
                {
                    icon_active: false,
                },
                { [a]: true },
            )
            this.setState(newState);
        }
    }

    render = () => {
        const { icon_active  } = this.state;
        var myCarousel = this.state.myImagesArray.map(function (index) {
            return (
                <View key={index}>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => activateCarouselButton('icon_active')} >
                        <Image
                            source={icon_active ? require('../Image/active@2x.png') : require('../Image/disabled@2x.png')} />
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            );
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <Carousel
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                    {myCarousel}
                </Carousel>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold `key` of the icon in the **icon_active** state, not a boolean. This gives you a hunch on how to do it:

```
render() {
  const { icon_active } = this.state;
  return (
    this.state.myImagesArray.map((image) => {
      return (
         <View key={image.key}>
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => activateCarouselButton(image.key)}>
             <Image source={icon_active === image.key ? require('../Image/active@2x.png') : require('../Image/disabled@2x.png')} />
           </TouchableHighlight>
         </View>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  <Image source={this.props.secureTextEntry ? 
  require('../../assets/images/signup/Showpassword.png') : 
  require('../../assets/images/signup/Hidepassword.png')} />
```

Comment: Please provide some context.